# strange problem in a c++ program with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

I wrote this simple c++ program and I got some strange results that I don't understand (results are described in the line comments)

```
int arr[3] {1, 2, 3};
int* p{ nullptr };

p = arr;
std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2]; // prints 1 2 3, OK

p = arr;
std::cout << *(p++) << " " << *(p++) << " " << *(p); // prints 2 1 3 ??

p = arr;
std::cout << *p << " " << *(++p) << " " << *(++p); // prints 3 3 3 ??

p = arr;
std::cout << *p << " "; ++p;
std::cout << *p << " "; ++p;
std::cout << *p; // prints 1 2 3, OK
```

it seems that the pointer increments along a std::cout concatenation don't work.
What's wrong in my idea?
I supposed it should have worked.
best

*final edit*: I was using c++14, I switched to c++20 and now it works properly
thank you everybody!

Comment: You assigned `p` to `nullptr`, so what happens when you do `nullptr[0]`?  The value of `p` is `nullptr` when the first `std::cout` is encountered.

Comment: i seem to remeber that the order of evaluation of operator overloads (<<) was not defeined in earlier c++ version but is now specified . What version of c++ did you use

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, since you are accessing a `nullptr`. The compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants at that point. For one I'm using, it actually just removes all the code and just generates the `ud2` assembly instruction (invalid op code)

Comment: I assume the whole nullptr thing is just a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int* p{ nullptr };
> std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2];
> ```

This is *Undefined Behavior*, as you are dereferencing `nullptr`, `p` does not point at valid memory yet.

> ```
> p = arr;
> std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2];
> ```

This is well-defined behavior.  `p` points at valid memory, is always incremented before dereferenced, and is incremented in a deterministic and valid manner.  This is the same as if you had written the following instead:

```
std::cout << *(p+0) << " " << *(p+1) << " " << *(p+2);
```

> ```
> p = arr;
> std::cout << *(p++) << " " << *(p++) << " " << *(p);
>
> p = arr;
> std::cout << *p << " " << *(++p) << " " << *(++p);
> ```

Both of these are *Undefined Behavior* prior to C++17, because the [order in which chained `operator<<` calls are evaluated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) is not guaranteed in earlier versions, the compiler is free to evaluate them in whatever order it wants.  This is no longer the case in C++17 onward.

> ```
> p = arr;
> std::cout << *p << " "; ++p;
> std::cout << *p << " "; ++p;
> std::cout << *p;
> ```

This is well-defined behavior.  `p` points at valid memory, is always dereferenced before incremented, and is incremented in a deterministic and valid manner.